# Ajax post is not working after wordpress integration in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, laravel

Ajax post is working fine before I integrate wordpress in my project. After the wordpress integration its shows a `404 error`. But when try to debug using firebug we can see that the response is correct.

Wordpress integration code,

```
require  "..".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."public". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'blog'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'wp-blog-header.php';
```

Ajax code,

```
var token = "{{csrf_token()}}";
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "{{URL::to('ajax/country/load_cities')}}",
    data: {  '_token':token, 'country_id': 12 } 
}).done(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Controller function,

```
public function loadCountryCities(){
    echo "response";
    exit;
}
```

routes.php,

```
Route::post('ajax/country/load_cities', array('as' => 'countryloadcities','uses' => 'CitiesController@loadCountryCities'));
```

The code working fine when remove the require statement. How can we make works the post response too ?

Comment: Could you try to add `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);` just before your require statement?

Comment: Do you have any PHP error when you try to reach the `ajax/country/load_cities` url in your browser?

Comment: @vard only 404 error

Comment: And if you don't require _wp-blog-header.php_ you don't get that 404, right? If so, could you try to include _wp-config.php_ instead? It require the WP core too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include *wp-config.php* instead of *wp-blog-header.php*.

*wp-blog-header.php* is used to include the Wordpress Core + the post functionalities in order to display a template. Considering you don't send a valid post url this is probably why it was breaking. Instead, *wp-config.php* is including the WP core only and can be used in any external file to work with WP functions.